# Characterization of Moment Generating Function of Hitting Time

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stopping-times, moment-generating-functions

Suppose that $x_t$ follows the stochastic differential equation: 
\begin{align*}
 dx_t = (a - b x_t) dt + \sigma x_t dB_t
\end{align*}
Where $B_t$ is a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion, and $a, b>0$ are constant. 
Let $\bar x > 0$.
Let $\tau := \inf \{t: x_t  = \bar x \}$ be the first time $x_t$ ``hits'' the barrier $\bar x$. 
For $x < \bar x$, I want to characterize the moment generating function $f_{\theta} (x) := \mathbb{E}^x \left[ e^{- \theta \tau} \right]$ using an ordinary differential equation with two boundary conditions (in other word, a standard boundary value problem). I would like to argue that the following Kolmogorov-backward equation, in addition to the following two boundary conditions, are sufficient to fully characterize the moment generating function of interest.
\begin{align*}
 0 = - \theta f_\theta (x) + (a - bx)f_\theta' (x) + \frac{1}{2} x^2 \sigma^2 f_\theta'' (x)
\end{align*}
The boundary conditions are as follows: 
\begin{align*}
 f_\theta(\bar x) &= 1 \\
 \lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} f_\theta(x) &= 0 
\end{align*}
The ordinary differential equation is elliptic, but presents a singularity at x = 0, meaning that I cannot use standard existence/uniqueness results of boundary value problems to establish that the BVP above fully characterize the function $f_\theta$. Can anyone (a) opine whether the BVP I have truly characterizes $f_\theta$, and (b) recommend papers I should look at re: existence/uniqueness of solutions to this type of BVP with singularity at a finite number of points? Thanks.